# Wysiwyg custom attribute with cms directives is not working

Tags: image, widgets, widget

I have a wysiwyg custom attribute.

Insert an image there:
[image]

But in the html code source I see this one:

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/article1.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

Instead of

```
<img src="imagepath/article1.jpg" alt="" />
```

This html source is generated by this code:

```
<?php echo $_item->getPreview() ?>
```

Why wysiwyg cms directive was not replaced with image url?

Comment: What do you mean 'in a correct way'?

Comment: To get <img src="imagepath/article1.jpg" /> instead of {{media...}}.

Comment: That is how magento wysiwyg works. During output '{{media url="wysiwyg/article1.jpg"}}' will be changed to 'imagepath/article1.jpg'. So what is your exact problem?

Comment: It doesn't change it)

Comment: Can you please update the question with code of form field definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom attribute with wysiwyg cannot be simply outputted.

If it contains cms directives `{{media url="wysiwyg/images_2_.jpg"}}`, it should be preprocessed with `catalog/output` helper.

```
<?php
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attribute = $product->getYourAttribute();
    $attributeName = 'your_attribute_name';
    echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($product, $attribute, $attributeName);
?>
```

**Important**

Check that in sql upgrade your custom attribute was created correctly with all necessary properties

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'                    => 'General',
    'input'                    => 'textarea',
    'type'                     => 'text',
    'label'                    => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'                  => '',
    'visible'                  => true,
    'required'                 => false,
    'visible_on_front'         => true,
    'global'                   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'wysiwyg_enabled'          => true,
    //these attribute is very important for processing cms directives
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
));
```

Also make sure that "Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories" in System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend is set to "yes".

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't write that attribute is like cms page attribute. It's not for catalog entity. So I found an answer: 
`<?php $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
$processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
$html = $processor->filter($_item->getPreview()); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Use helper class

Instead of `<?php echo $_product->getDescription();?>`,

use `<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getDescription()), 'description'); ?>`.

For me, its solved same issue on magento version 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.2.3
Please check that attribute you want to display meet the conditions:
$attribute->getIsHtmlAllowedOnFront()
$attribute->getIsWysiwygEnabled()

This check present in 
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Output::productAttribute